# How do I load videos before other html elements?

Tags: html, css, video

I have built a site that has a background video and looking to improve on the user experience. Currently all text elements load before the background video does. What I want is for the video to load first before the text does, how can i achieve this? Below is the css and html snippet I'm using. You can also use this test url to view the site http://www.convenantkingsandqueens.academy

```css
video.fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<header id="page-top" class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-vertical-center">
    <img src="images/tmw_logo.png" class="img-responsive logo_img" alt="Timeline Media Workx Logo" style="height: 200px; width: 450px;">
    <video class="fullscreen" src="videos/bkg/sample.mp4" autobuffer autoloop loop autoplay></video>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Try using js/jQuery and check when video is loaded and than show text

Comment: If you want full control over your loading sequence, you have to do that in Javascript. You should send Ajax requests and if they are resolved, do the next request. This is not very user-friendly though. Try reading up on [ajax requests](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: @Randy Though javascript isn't one of my strong skills but i'll challenge myself and write some code to fix this loading sequence. Besides the why the background video loads, what else do i need to fix to make it more user-friendly?

Answer (score 0):

The preload attribute specifies if and how the author thinks that the video should be loaded when the page loads.

The preload attribute allows the author to provide a hint to the browser about what he/she thinks will lead to the best user experience. This attribute may be ignored in some instances.

```
<video class="fullscreen" src="videos/bkg/sample.mp4" autobuffer autoloop loop preload="metadata"></video>
```

**Note:** The preload attribute is ignored if autoplay is present. It does not work in IE browser

Comment: Using only the preload attribute doesn't play the video automatically, so I tried both. There seems to be some improvement now but I love to know what you think of it now. I would appreciate if everyone who has contributed have a look at it as well. Cheers.

Comment: Your background video is constantly pausing for me, and I am on a 25Mb fibre broadband connection.  If this was on a mobile connection, there would be even more pausing.  You would be better off using a selection of stills from the video in a slider, and then having a "See Sample Video" button.  Background video is rarely if ever used by sites, and there is a good reason for that, most broadband cannot cope with it.